# Integrate a JQuery AJAX functions that can populate simple UI elements and a JQuery AJAX DataTable Function that populates a UI table element?

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, jquery-ui, datatables

Here is the information about my development environment:

-Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

-.NET Framework 4.0

-jQuery-2.1.4.min.js

-jQuery DataTables 1.10.7

- Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1

-jQuery UI 1.11.2

UI elements in the ASPX page's are populated by invoking Jquery AJAX functions.

Therefore, I use Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1 to build the JSON data.

In one of the pages, I have some span UI elements that get populated and a drop down list box that gets populated by a JQuery Ajax Function.

However, I also have a UI Table element that gets populated another  JQUery  AJax  DataTable Function.

Basically, I am invoking 2 separate JQuery Ajax functions to populate the UI elements of the ASPX page.

The reason for invoking 2 separate JQuery AJax function is because I only know how to use the JQUery  AJax  DataTable Function to populate the UI Table Element.

I basically don't know how to implement a JQuery AJAX function that will populate the span UI Elements, drop down list box UI element, and the UI TAble Element.

How could I consolidate all the JSON into a single JQuery AJAX function?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to return additional data with the datatables response, thus avoiding multiple ajax calls?

Comment: :) Correct.  I feel silly that I couldn't explain it more briefly, but I like the way you expressed how you understand the requirement.

Comment: You can return custom data in the json, in v1.9 it was called [fnServerData](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnServerData), and in 1.10 I _think_ you use the ajax.data option.  I only mention the legacy method because I can't find much info about the 1.10 approach.